# How to get array of all instances of table end their sub-components Node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, get, request

I'm trying to create a quiz application with node.js as a backend language. I am trying to get all the questions and for every question in the array another "answers" array with every answer for that question. I want to get this information as a get request.

[pic of my database tables](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zqvQ3.png)

the format of the output I want would look like this:

```
[
    {
        "questionText": "Question1How much do you like Python?",
        "answers": [
            {
                "answerText": "Q1RESPONSE OPTION 1",
                "isCorrect": false,
                "score": 0
            },
            {
                "answerText": "Q1RESPONSE OPTION 2",
                "isCorrect": true,
                "score": 10
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "questionText": "Question2How much do you like Python?",
        "answers": [
            {
                "answerText": "Q2RESPONSE OPTION 1",
                "isCorrect": false,
                "score": 0
            },
            {
                "answerText": "Q2RESPONSE OPTION 2",
                "isCorrect": true,
                "score": 10
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

So far I have made this controller function for a get request

```
const getAllAnswersForQuestion = async (req, res) => {
  try {
    let question_id = req.params.question_id;
    const question = await Question.findOne({ where: { id: question_id } });
    const answers = await Answer.findAll({
      where: {
        questionId: question_id
      }
    })
    if (answers.length > 0) {
      res.status(200).send({ question, answers });
    } else
      res.status(404).json({ message: "question has 0 answers" });

  } catch (e) {
    console.error(e);
    res.status(500).send({ message: "server error" });
  }
};
```

But the output I receive looks like so:

```
{
    "question": {
        "id": 1,
        "questionText": "Q1How much do you like Python?",
        "testId": 1
    },
    "answers": [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "answerText": "Q1RESPONSE OPTION 1",
            "isCorrect": false,
            "score": 0,
            "questionId": 1
        },
        {
            "id": 2,
            "answerText": "Q1RESPONSE OPTION 2",
            "isCorrect": true,
            "score": 10,
            "questionId": 1
        }
    ]
}
```

Do you have any idea of how I could create a function to append to the output object an array of subcomponents, like for every question to return the answers inside its object, and then return all the questions like specified above?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

So, you should have two schemas to be relationated, and on looking up for Questions just populate each answer.

Example:

```js
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

const questionSchema = Schema({
  _id: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
  questionText: String,
  /// ...
  answers: [{ type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Answer' }]
});

const Question = mongoose.model('Question ', questionSchema );

const answerSchema = Schema({
  answerText: String,
  isCorrect: Boolean,
  /// ...
});

const Answer = mongoose.model('Answer', answerSchema );
```

Looking for questions with it all answers:

```js
const getAllAnswersForQuestion = async (req, res) => {
  try {
    let question_id = req.params.question_id;
    const question = await Question.findOne({ where: { id: question_id } }).populate("answers") // populate the property you want, in this case "asnwers"

    if (question .length > 0) {
      res.status(200).send({ question});
    } else
      res.status(404).json({ message: "question has 0 answers" });

  } catch (e) {
    console.error(e);
    res.status(500).send({ message: "server error" });
  }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

So, I have managed to resolve it eventually by creating another function, I don't know if this will help somebody ever but I will leave it here. The `raw: true` part is very important for getting only the data in the table, without the additional things added to the object in the browser.

```
const getAllQuestions = async (req, res) => {
      try {
        let test_id = req.params.test_id;
        const questions = await Question.findAll({raw:true, where:{
          testId:test_id
        }}).then(async (questionsFound) => {
          for (let i = 0; i < questionsFound.length; i++) {
            questionsFound[i].answers = await getAllAnswersQuestion(questionsFound[i].id)
          }
          return questionsFound;
        });

        res.status(200).send(questions);
      } catch (e) {
        console.error(e);
        res.status(500).send({ message: "server error" });
      }
    }

    const getAllAnswersQuestion = async (id) => {    
        const answers = await Answer.findAll({
          where: {
            questionId: id
          },
          raw: true
        })

        return answers
    };
```

I didn't want to use mongoose because it is something new for me.